# IE11 delays render until mouseover or mouse click with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I've this functionality which allows user know when a change has been performed on an item by adding an orange dot next the item icon, so if this is a new item and user clicks on the icon a modal is displayed with a form, if any change on that form is perfomed the orange dot (which is an icon as well) appears next to the item's icon. This functionality is working with Chrome and Edge but I'm also supporting IE11, the problem is IE11 is not showing the orange dot icon when a change is performed. I reviewed the dom and the orange icon is there but is not visible until I click on the dom's element or when I click the section where the orange dot is suppose to be, in that moment the orange dot appears.

following is the original state, when I click the comment icon a modal appears with the form:

[image]

```
<div class="action-container">
   <span class="action-comment">
      <i class="comment-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

after a change is performed I got this in the dom:

```
<div class="action-container">
   <span class="action-comment">
      <i class="comment-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="action-orange-dot">
      <div class="orange-dot"></div>
   </span>
</div>
```

but in the browser the result is the same:

[image]

until I click where the orange dot is suppose to be

[image]

I have the compatible meta tag but there is no difference with or without it.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in my side. Is there any error in console in IE? Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using some online code editors like [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so that we can have a test and can have a better understanding of the issue? Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a drop down value, the value was in the dom, but it wasn't displayed until I hover it or click anywhere on the screen. My work around was to add a focus on the target element when the drop down option is selected - e.target.focus(). Not sure if it helps, but might be useful for anyone else.